# What is a "dumb" framebuffer?

Tags: unix, operating-system, x11, framebuffer, xvfb

I used [Xvfb](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) recently for running my tests using Jenkins on an Ubuntu instance. On researching up on Xvfb, I understood what the *X* and *virtual* part meant in Xvfb. I got stuck at the meaning of "dumb framebuffer". According to [X.org](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml):

> It emulates a dumb framebuffer using virtual memory.

What does *dumb framebuffer* mean in this statement? I understand what framebuffer means. Is the *dumb* word in there because there is no physical display output?

Comment: No, it's because there's no hardware acceleration or any advanced functionality.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. You can convert your comment to an answer and I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dumb framebuffer is one that doesn't have hardware acceleration or any advanced functionality.